# Intellij Idea and KDE 5.8 shortcuts do not work

Tags: linux, intellij-idea, kde-plasma, shortcut

I have Idea 13 and KDE 5.8. Many Idea hotkeys don't works. For example using of <kbd>ctrl + shift + N</kbd> in Idea works like <kbd>ctrl + N</kbd> ignoring <kbd>shift</kbd> key. The same way for <kbd>ctrl + alt + shift + S</kbd> hotkey. instead of it fires <kbd>ctrl + alt + S</kbd> against ignoring <kbd>shift</kbd> key. But in Google Chrome combination <kbd>ctrl + shift + T</kbd> works fine!

Can anybody help? Please don't offer for me changing of hotkeys.

Comment: KDE allows to swap and reassign modifier keys. Maybe you want to check the settings under hardware > keyboard > advanced and check whether something is strange there. I myself used Intellij under a KDE desktop for quite a while without any issues, although I am still using an older KDE version (4.14).

Comment: Hi. i use `ctrl+shift` for language switching. first i think what it's root cause of my problem. but later i found in Crome ctrl+shift+t works fine..